# php dom remplazar etiquetas html

Tags: php, html, dom

Hola amigos quisiera saber como remplazar algunas etiquetas html,
reemplazar las etiquetas `div` que no tengas `class` o `style` por etiqueta `p`

tengo este codigo:

```
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="media_embed">
                <div style="xxx">
                    <div style="xxx">
                        <div style="xxx"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>
```

y quisiera que quedara de esta manera:

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
    <p>
        <div class="media_embed">
                <div style="xxx">
                    <div style="xxx">
                        <div style="xxx"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
</p>
```

intente de esta manera pero no lo consegui:
aqui esta mi codigo php

```
<?php
      $embeds= $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
      foreach ($embeds as $embed) {
          $class = $embed->getAttribute('class');
          if ($class == "")
          {
            $link= $dom->createElement('p');
            $embed->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $embed);
          }
      }
?>
```

me podrian ayudar porfavor

Answer (score 2):

Usando [`PHP:DOM`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.dom.php), podrías hacerlo así:

```
<?php

$html = '<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="media_embed">
                <div style="xxx">
                    <div style="xxx">
                        <div style="background-color:red;"><p>Rojo</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$nodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

// Convertimos la "nodeList" a arreglo
// de lo contrario al pasar "divs" hijos a un "p"
// se pierde la referencia en la "nodeList"
$divs = iterator_to_array($nodeList);

foreach ($divs as $div) {

    // Si no tiene atributos
    if (!$div->hasAttributes()) {

        $p = $doc->createElement('p');

        // Trasladamos todos los hijos del "div" al nuevo "p"
        while ($div->hasChildNodes()) {
            $p->appendChild($div->firstChild);
        }

        // Reemplazamos el "div" por el "p"
        $div->parentNode->replaceChild($p, $div);
    }
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

<kbd>[`Demo`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3fa9f8730bdeb6b937fc884eb64816203e15f063)</kbd>

Comment: Dice que debe ser en PHP puro, al menos eso he entendido. Si no, con una sola línea de código jQuery se haría: `$('div:not([class])').contents().unwrap().wrap('<p/>');`

Comment: @A. Cedano, mi código es 100% PHP. DOM es una extensión que normalmente esta activa por defecto.

Comment: De acuerdo. Con el regex lo resolvemos con 3 líneas de código y sería más eficiente, pues no habría necesidad de manipular el DOM. Al menos eso creo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Justamente lo que no hay que hacer es usar regex en estos casos, jamás para analizar HTML. Una expresión regular se rompe muy fácilmente. Ejemplo: https://regex101.com/r/qGvXub/1

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

**A. USANDO PHP**

[Probar código php](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/95ac400fea4fcf1a09d2c06d01764c520ab4a6cc).

**Nota:** El html fue formateado correctamente, pues había por ejemplo divs sin cerrar en el html de la pregunta

```
$html='<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="media_embed"> </div>
<div style="xxx"></div>
<div style="xxx"></div>
<div style="background-color:red;"><p>Rojo</p></div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>';
$regex = '#<div>(.+?)</div>#s';
$result = preg_replace( $regex, 
    '<p>$1</p>', 
    $html
);
echo $result;
```

**Resultado:**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<div class="media_embed"> </div>
<div style="xxx"></div>
<div style="xxx"></div>
<div style="background-color:red;"><p>Rojo</p></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

---

**B. USANDO JQUERY:**

Prueba en [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/9fvpz19m/4/). He puesto un color rojo en uno que no se cambia para que veas el resultado.

Simplemente con esto en jQuery:

```
$('div:not([class])').contents().unwrap().wrap('<p/>');
```

Comment: gracias pero tengo que hacerlo con php, saludos

Comment: PHP se combina con jQuery. Bueno, veré una solución en PHP de todos modos. Ahora vuelvo.

Comment: He editado la pregunta haciéndolo a través de PHP.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo ¿Cuál es el fallo en concreto? Viendo los divs originales, algunos están mal, por ejemplo, al principio, hay dos div de apertura sin cierre. Eso no sería problema del regex, sino de un html mal escrito. En el enlace phpfiddle corregiré el html y te probaré que el código funciona. Creo que en la pregunta no se pedía una función que repare un html mal escrito, sino que reemplace los div que no tengan class o style. Y eso es lo que hace la función. Supongo que tu solución daría el mismo problema con divs erróneos. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano, si miras detenidamente, el `HTML` no esta mal, todo `div` que abre, eventualmente es cerrado. Ademas, el OP ha puesto el resultado esperado y mi respuesta devuelve dicho resultado.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Si el HTML del ejemplo es erróneo, el resultado lo será. En tu caso el HTML que devuelve la función es erróneo. Por ejemplo, como tiene dos divs al principio, sin cerrar, tu código devuelve 2 `<p>`seguidas. Se supone que debes cerrar la 1ª antes de abrir la segunda. Y tiene divs dentro de <p>... Yo entendí la pregunta como **obtener una función que reemplace todos aquellos divs que no tengan nombre de clase o estilo**. Eso es lo que he hecho. Y si se me entrega un HTML erróneo tendré que señalar que es erróneo. Aquí el único fallo es el HTML y sobre eso ninguna función sirve.

Comment: @A.Cedano, un `div` puede contener `div`s, eso no es un error. El primer `div` cierra el final de todo, es decir contiene todo el `HTML`

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Lo que digo es que en el resultado de tu HTML hay divs dentro de <p>, lo cual es incorrecto. De todos modos eso es lo de menos. En mi opinión la función es totalmente útil en un código HTML correcto. ¿O se trataba de hacer una función que corrigiese un código incorrecto? Ese es a mi juicio el punto central del asunto. Sería absurdo crear funciones que adivinen ese tipo de errores, ya que habría tantas funciones como usuarios con códigos erróneos. Me sorprende que te centres en un aparente resultado erróneo fruto de un HTML erróneo y no en la utilidad de la función.